# Matching a pattern multiple times in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

The aim is to replace doubles by kind of a distribution functon, i.e. 
transform strings like this one

```
0.5 * x + 0.5 * y
```

into a string like:

```
IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)] * x + IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)] * y
```

I have written the following function:

```
    public static String replaceDoubles(String stoEx) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.[0-9]\\d*))");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stoEx);
    while (m.find()) {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
        String dStr = String.valueOf(d);
        String[] parts = dStr.split("\\.");
        int lower = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
        int upper = lower + 1;
        double decimalPart = d - lower;
        decimalPart = round(decimalPart, 2);
        double rest = round(1 - decimalPart, 2);
        String replacement = "IntPMF[(" + lower + ";" + rest + ")(" + upper + ";" + decimalPart + ")]";
        stoEx = stoEx.replaceAll(m.group(1), replacement);
    }
    return stoEx;
}
```

The problem is that with this function I get the following output (for the above mentioned string):

```
IntPMF[(0;IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)])(1;IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)])] * x + IntPMF[(0;IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)] (1;IntPMF[(0;0.5)(1;0.5)])] * y
```

The doubles 0.5 get replaced several times...

Any suggestions for a solution would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: you need to tell how the input gets mapped to the output. i.e. how the output is formed, how does it work for any other doubles, or are you expecting the results for that one particular input?

Comment: The method should work for any double. For example "0.52" should become "IntPMF[(0;0.48)(1;0.52)]". This means the number is 0 is 48% of the cases and 1 in 52% of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, You can use something like this. To round values and get the interpretation, it is recommended to use a `DecimalFormatter`. Avoid using JDK internal libraries for this.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( "0.00" );

    //0.52 -> IntPMF[(0;0.48)(1;0.52)]
    String stoEx = "0.5 * x + 0.32222* y";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+\\.\\d+)" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( stoEx );
    String result = "";
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner( "+" );
    String[] splitString = stoEx.split( "\\+" );
    for( String subString: splitString )
    {
        if( m.find() )
        {
            String fracPart = m.group( 1 ).split( "\\." )[1];
            String fracOne = df.format( 1 - ( Integer.parseInt( fracPart ) / Math.pow( 10.0, fracPart.length() ) ) );
            String fracTwo = df.format( ( Integer.parseInt( fracPart ) / Math.pow( 10.0, fracPart.length() ) ) );
            String resultEx = "IntPMF[(" + 0 + ";" + fracOne + ")(" + 1 + ";" + fracTwo + ")]";
            result = subString.replaceFirst( m.group( 1 ), resultEx );
            stringJoiner.add( result );
        }
    }
    System.out.println( stringJoiner.toString() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. However, I added a small edit because of the requirements.

Comment: That's fine, I have just provided a working solution, changing that as per your needs is up to you. If the above answer satisfies you, please mark it as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I've ommited computation part as you're interested in clear text replacements:

```
    final private static Pattern doublePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+");
    final private static String outputTemplate = "IntPMF[(0;%1$s)(1;%2$s)]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "0.5 * x + 0.32222* y";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int pos = 0;
        Matcher matcher = doublePattern.matcher(text);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group());
            String s1 = "s1"; // compute first parameter here
            String s2 = "s2"; // compute second parameter here

            // add part before matching
            sb.append(text.substring(pos, matcher.start()));
            pos = matcher.end();
            // add template
            sb.append(String.format(outputTemplate, s1, s2));
        }
        // add leftovers
        sb.append(text.substring(pos));

        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```